# How to get a piece of a list?

Tags: f#

I have a list like `[1..12]` and I would like to get a piece like `[4..9]`. No clue how I can do that, I'm new with F#. I don't know if there is a built-in method for that, but I would like to know the manual way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To give an immediate answer to your question: how do you take a piece of a list? Pattern matching.

You can use pattern matching to write a function that extracts a range from a list. The basic algorithm is *skip each element of the list while E < Min, then take each element while E <= Max*. Something like this:

```ml
let range min max xs =
  let rec skipWhile f = function
    | x::xs when f x -> skipWhile f xs
    | xs -> xs
  let rec takeWhile f acc = function
    | x::xs when f x -> takeWhile f (x::acc) xs
    | _ -> List.rev acc
  xs
  |> skipWhile ((>) min)
  |> takeWhile ((>=) max) []

[1..12] |> range 4 9
> val it : int list = [4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9]
```

Answer (score 8):

```
[1..12] |> List.filter (fun x -> x >= 4 && x <= 9)
```

or

```
[1..12] |> Seq.skip 3 |> Seq.take 6 |> Seq.toList
```

Lists don't support slicing, but if you use an array instead you can also do this:

```
[|1..12|].[3..8]
```

(note 3..8 instead of 4..9 because of 0-based indexing)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use the Ocaml-like subset of *F#* you probably want to use the [List](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html) standard module, probably its `filter` function.

Otherwise, a tail recursive function with matching could do.